# Web Core API Post request get blocked, sometimes

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this AJAX call to my Web Core API;

```
saveProperty = function (url, data, callback, errorCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: "Post",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "text"
            })
                .done(callback)
                //.fail(errorCallback);
                .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Something went wrong: " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                    errorCallback();
                });
        }
```

Sometimes it works, more often it does not.
When I use Fiddler and it works, I see 
[image]

And when it doesn't I see;

EDIT - I can be more helpful now in describing this problem.
if I have Fiddler up and running before I lanch the aplication in development, I do not get this bug.
Otherwise I do get this bug.
Why is that? I would love to know.

[image]

The error is HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized

Why would this happen with the same code?

Comment: looks like a CORS issue to me;  the second screenshot shows an `options` header, not a `post` header....

Comment: I have Cors set up. What I am now finding is that if I have Fiddler running before I launch the application, it works, otherwise it doesn't. Hard to make sense of that.

Comment: the second screenshot shows a different origin; `localhost:17972` vs `localhost:12528`.  This *would seem to suggest* that CORS is, in fact, not working properly.

Comment: Because starting up the proxy after you have already authenticated to the web app breaks your authentication. Does it start working again if you ctrl-F5 refresh and login again?